# divs, textareas, text and cursor detection

Tags: javascript, html, size, contenteditable

I have the following problems:

1.) I want to use a contenditable div or a textarea ( preferrably a contenteditable div because I can also use there html tags, not just text ), as a writing pad. However I want the writing to STOP once the cursor reaches the BOTTOM RIGHT corner of the div/textarea. This seems hard to implement. I have managed with max-height and overflow:hidden to make the element ( div / textarea ) to not expand, however the user can still type, it will just be invisible, something unwanted. What I want is the writing to stop when the cursor reaches the bottom right corner and then go on, on a new empty "page".

My first idea was to use some monospace font and calculate the max chars allowed but the issue is that 1st not all browsers show the same number of monospace characters of the same font, per line and 2nd the div can be variable in size, not constant.

The ideal would be a div so that i can enter html tags ( bold, italic, etc. ) and the div that shows the content can be of a different size, depending on the screen resolution.

2.) Given a div which represents a "page" which gets filled with a text/html from the database, how can I show only the content that fills the div, and when the user presses a "next page" button, show the next content. This seems undoable to me, figuring out via javascript how much content can fill into the div.

Any ideas on these two correlated problems would be greatly appreciated

No flash, no java, no plugins. only: html,css,javascript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have an idea, which might or might not work. Each time the box is modified (onkeyup, probably), append a span tag to it, then calculate its offset from the parent with jQuery. Compare that with the dynamic width and height (also calculated with jQuery) and see if it's at the end. If so, do whatever. Somewhat convoluted, but might just work, and after all, no one said it would be easy :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code.

`<div id="editable_div"></div>`

```
var content_id = document.getElementById("editable_div");  

    max = 10;

    //binding keyup/down events on the contenteditable div
    $('#'+content_id).keyup(function(e){ check_charcount(content_id, max, e); });
    $('#'+content_id).keydown(function(e){ check_charcount(content_id, max, e); });

    function check_charcount(content_id, max, e)
    {   
        if(e.which != 8 && $('#'+content_id).text().length > max)
        {
           // $('#'+content_id).text($('#'+content_id).text().substring(0, max));
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: there are different problems with a counting the characters approach:

a) i will need to use a monospace font

b) not crossbrowser ( need to check for browser vendor )

c) would only work with text content, not HTML

and thus I would like to avoid it if possible..